# MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) graphic card issues

Tags: mac, graphics, bug, gpu, touch-bar

First of all this is my hardware:
[image]

When i power on my new mac book pro (with touch bar) i figured out a strange problem (i think is related with my graphic card).

This is the procedure to get that issue:

- Power on my mac
- Type my credentials
- the first window i open (in this case the "spotlight" window) appears in this way:
  [image]
  There are a lot of white pixel ...
- Then if i close the spotlight window and i open again that problem disappear.

If i restart my mac i don't have this problem. It only happen if i shut down my mac and then power on it again. In this example i used "spotlight" but happen the same with the "Finder" app.

**---EDIT---**

My GPU:

- Intel HD Graphics 530
- Radeon Pro 450

Yes i have this issue on my interal display (external monitor never used).

**---EDIT 2---**
`SMC`and `NVRAM`didn't fix the problem.

**---EDIT 3---**
After many call to "Apple Care" they figured out that my mac book pro has some hardware issues. They offer to me a substitution. Of course i said yes. In 2 weeks they will send to me a new one.

Comment: I've posted an answer (at least as a starting point), but if that doesn't help can you please edit your question to include the full About This Mac screenshot? I ask because your model MBP comes with both the Intel HD Graphics 530 **and** either an AMD Radeon Pro 450, 455, or 460. Your screenshot only shows the Intel HD Graphics 530. Also, can you clarify whether you're only using your internal screen?

Comment: I think you need to take this back to Apple.  It looks like you have a graphics card issue.

Comment: Is this a screenshot or a photo? If it's a screenshot, then it may be less likely to be a hardware issue--graphics card problems tend to show up directly on the display, but not in screenshots. (But there are exceptions, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

That does seem a little strange. As a starting point it may be worth resetting both your SMC and NVRAM. Instructions follow.

**Resetting the SMC on your particular MBP**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable plugged in
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**Resetting the NVRAM on Late-2016 MacBook Pro models**

For all Late-2016 MacBook Pro models (with and without Touch Bar) follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.**
3. **Keep these keys pressed down for at least 20 seconds!**
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

Once you've tried these, let us know how you go.

Comment: thank you, i will try tomorrow and i will let you know. But one thing i figure out: if i remove the flag on the "let the mac to switch between GPU" (so if i use the ATI Radeon GPU) the problem disappear. If i flag again that option the problem come back. It's like my Iris GPU the responsable of my issue.

Comment: Yes, getting you to change those settings was going to be my next step if resetting the SMC and NVRAM have no effect. Basically we need to isolate which GPU may be causing the issue. Beyond that it's a hardware diagnostics test to see if it will generate an error for you. I suspect in the end it'll be a visit to Apple, but hopefully it won't come to that.

Comment: so i wil try to reset my SMC and the NVRAM or i will go directly to an Apple Center ? Could be a software issue ? maybe the last Sierra update ? thank you.

Comment: If an Apple Store is convenient, then do that. However, an SMC and NVRAM reset are easy to do so there's no harm in that. And yes, it _could_ be a software issue. Another easy option is just to call Apple Care and they will talk you through a number of steps and organise an Apple Store appointment if necessary. Whatever you do, if you get a resolution then report back here as it may help others.

Comment: Ok thank you i will try NVRAM and SMC reset and i will let you know.

Comment: HI i reset NVRAM and SMC. but the problem remain :(

Comment: Okay, I feared as much. We can advise you how to run diagnostics etc, but it may be easier for you (since you have warranty) to just call Apple Care as they can talk you through it over the phone rather than you having to keep coming back here. Your call. Good luck!

Comment: Today i get a call from the Apple Care, they removed: `~/Library/Caches` and `~/Library/Preferences` folders; but the problem  persists. next week i will send back my 3000 box mac book pro to Apple. (Incredible, my old laptop with linux and paid just 300 box... is still there and it's doing a great job after 4 intense years).